# Restrict Launch Services from registering App bundles

Tags: macos, mac

Is it possible to restrict Launch Services on Mac OSX (I'm on Yosemite but I guess the same applies to older versions) from registering certain App Bundles?

For example, if I have on my disk several app bundle copies of the same application, I don't want them all to appear in the "Open With" menu for the type they handle. I want only the one in /Applications to be "registered".

I know that I can clean duplicates in the "Open With" menu but that is not the case (I actually have those app bundles on disk in a different places). I also don't want to rename those app bundles, put them in hidden folder or archive them.

Is it possible to tweak this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lsregister -u` to unregister an application:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -u /path/to/application.app`

The application might get registered again at some point however.

If you just want to remove an application from Open With menus, run `defaults delete /path/to/Application.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleDocumentTypes`. Modifying the `Info.plist` breaks the code signature if the application is signed, and it has caused sandboxed applications to crash on launch since 10.8.

Comment: For others coming across this answer, `lsregister` is at `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister` on Mac High Sierra